# showing CPU usage in my program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I got this error when trying to show cpu usage in my GUI

> cputext = tk.Label(self, text="CPU", cpu)
>                                           ^
>   SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

This is my code

```
x = (2)
        while x > 0:
            cpu = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=False)
            cputext = tk.Label(self, text="CPU", cpu)
            cputext.pack()
```

When i print it like this, its ok but it is printing in console

```
print("CPU Usage :", cpu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cputext = tk.Label(self, text="CPU", cpu)
```

When you do like above, compiler treats `cpu` as an option for `Label` since all options are seperated by comma(just like `self`, `text`).

You need to format your string or create your string beforehand and pass it.

```
labelText = "CPU Usage : " +  str(cpu)
tk.Label(self, text = labelText)
```

OR

```
cputext = tk.Label(self, text="CPU Usage : {}".format(cpu))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no error now but nothing happens now, it wont open the GUI ?

Comment: It's because of your while loop. If you are not changing the value of x anywhere, it's infinite and since tkinter already has its infinite loop(mainloop) it doesn't show anything. You should look for .after method for continuous calls.

Comment: Thanks again, got it

Comment: I got one more question if you could help. So that script above i wanted to calculate linux server CPU, but it calculate my PC CPU, i have connected to my linux server with 

shell = spur.SshShell(hostname="ip", username="root", password="password", missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)

Comment: @JackZara Sorry, I don't know that much about those. You might want to ask another question after searching google/SO etc.